# Zerar hora do datetime com SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

Hoje meu `SELECT` retorna a seguinte data:

```
2017-11-16 10:37:16.000
```

Gostaria que retornasse `2017-11-16 00:00:00.000`, podem me ajudar com está formatação?

Comment: Qual seu banco de dados? Poste seu comando SQL

Comment: Eu não entendo muito de formatações, estou usando um select normal "SELECT DATA FROM TBL_DATAS"

Comment: qual seu banco de dados jovem ? mysql, firebird, sql-server, postgres ?

Comment: Qual seu banco de dados? Você quer que te retorne horas ou so a data (yyyy-MM-dd) basta?

Comment: O banco de dados é Sql Server

Comment: Preciso que retorne os segundos zerados R. Santos

Comment: então utilize  SELECT CURDATE() e pegue apenas a data, já que queres os minutos, segundos e hora zerado, não terá diferença para você

Comment: @user90864 alguma das resposta resolve sua necessidade? Se sim apenas marque a mesma como correta para auxiliar as futuras pessoas que possam ter a mesma dificuldade a achar a resposta mais rapido

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Você pode usar o format e passar a parte de horas zerada. Ex:

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00') AS DATE;
```

Answer (score 0):

Outra opção seria assim:

```
 SELECT to_char(DATA, 'yyyy-MM-dd 00:00:00.000') AS DATE from TBL_DATAS;
```